# Generating all possible conformations of an Intrinsically disordered protein

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, pharmacology

I want to simulate interaction between the bHLH-LZ domain of c-Myc encoded protein and a test ligand. Since the domain is intrinsically disordered, **I want to generate all possible conformations of the IDP to run several iterations of simulation, each time with a different conformation**. How can I do so? I would really appreciate if you could explain me what is the basis of these conformations and explain the concept?
Thank you!